# How to parse JSON in Ionic 2?

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am new in Ionic-2 hybrid App development and need to parse the JSON to use web services. I am not able to get any response from the server. I need to fetch data from the server and display it in "Product details page". My Json structure is

```
{
"id": 1,
"product": "Gerbera",
"product_type_id": 1,
"description": "Gerbera L. is a genus of plants Asteraceae. It was named in honour of German botanist and medical doctor Traugott Gerber | who travelled extensively in Russia and was a friend of Carl Linnaeus.",
"images": "http://factoryunlock.in/sundar/public/uploads/photos/07_17/1500965697_Growing-Gerbera-Flowers.jpg" }
```

My ionic Home.ts file code is:

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { EarthquakesProvider } from'../../providers/earthquakes/earthquakes';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
  providers: [EarthquakesProvider]
})
export class DetailsPage {

   // public DateList: Array<Object>;

    item: any;
     id: number;
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public earthquakes: EarthquakesProvider, public navParams: NavParams) {

         this.id = navParams.get('id');


    }
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.getEarthquakes(this.id);
}
    getEarthquakes(id) {
        this._earthquakes.loadEarthquakesdetails(id).subscribe(res => {
         this.item=res;

        });
    }

 }
```

My home.html file is:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title> Product Details</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="content-background">

  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item  style="background: #eee;border: 1px solid #888;height: 40px">

      {{ " Flower Name :" + product }} 

    </button>

    <ion-card >
      <div class=" col-50">
        <ion-item  style="width:100%">
          <img [src]="images" />
        </ion-item>
      </div>
      </ion-card>

      <button ion-item text-wrap style="background: #eee;border: 1px solid #888">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">


          {{" Discription :" +  description }}

</div>

      </button>

      <ion-list>
```

My provider code is:

```
loadEarthquakesdetails(id) {
        let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');  
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "eAKu0hiSYTqJTkV2yaBz6K1gVDK2TIDFcemjut3nlNoEJTRCNGEKHXRTi972");
        return this._http.get(`http://factoryunlock.in/sundar/public/api/v1/products/${id}`,{headers: headers})
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Screenshot of my app:

[image: screen 1]

Please suggest any solution. thank you.

Comment: User `item` object like `<img [src]="item.images" />`

Comment: @hrdkisback Not working. as there is no array, so how can it will detect items.images

Comment: its not array.. its object `item`..`item.images`

Comment: If it's array you have to take index like `item[i].images` but it's `json` 0bject so it will be `item.images`.

Comment: please check `http.get` response in subscribe block it's proper or not `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));`

Comment: can u suggest by editing my code..

Comment: I have edited your code please check the output of `console.log("Response Data " + JSON.stringify(res));` in browser's console.

Comment: Please refer to this post [pass data from one page to another for Navigation in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183698/how-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-for-navigation-in-ionic-2/45723410#45723410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Home.ts**

```
public item: any = {};
```

**Home.html**

```
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item style="background: #eee;border: 1px solid #888;height: 40px">
         Flower Name:  {{item?.product}}
        </button>
        <ion-card>
            <div class=" col-50">
                <ion-item style="width:100%">
                    <img [src]="item?.images" />
                </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-card>

        <button ion-item text-wrap style="background: #eee;border: 1px solid #888">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
              Discription : {{ item?.description }}
            </div>
          </button>


   </ion-list>
```